# Timezone issue - android

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the timezone in android

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
 System.out.println("timezone = " + tz.toString());
```

I should be getting

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000  .....
```

But when i print in ddms i get the below value

```
org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo@9e54425b
```

Comment: also how can i get only timezone region name like .. America/Los_Angeles or Europe/London ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html) the best way to get a text representation of a `TimeZone` is by using `getDisplayName`.

For the Olsen name, you can use [TimeZone.getID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getID%28%29).

Comment: @user1184100: see my edit. Perhaps you could create a local database or use an online service connecting the two?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I'll edit my answer for future reference if that's ok?